# Windows Failed to build gem native extension when installing Squib

Tags: ruby, squib

I know nothing about Ruby and have been trying to install the squib gem on Windows 10 with little success.

On my first attempt, I installed Ruby 2.6.5-1 using RubyInstaller.exe. I don't remember the error code, but squib did not install. (I believe it was "make failed, exit code 1")

Then, I found out that I did not install MSYS2. So, I uninstalled Ruby and reinstalled, making sure to install MSYS2. Squib refused to install properly yet again.

Therefore, I took to the help pages and found support in a thread called "[Windows install issue?](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1625597/windows-install-issue)". I was sure that this was my saving grace.

It wasn't.

I also tried the fixes listed in "[trouble downloading](https://github.com/andymeneely/squib/issues/232)" even though the OP's OS did not match mine. It didn't work.

I tried to install squib with bundler as well, but it did not work. I was not surprised.

I read some random thing somewhere saying that there may be conflicts with the newest version of Ruby. (2.6.5-1 at the time) So I used some downgrade Ruby magic to get to Ruby 2.5.7-??. Then something baffling happened. Squib failed to install. (The post was old and squib had been updated long ago)

UPDATE: I have uninstalled and reinstalled Ruby again. This time around I used the optional MSYS2 Update after installing MSYS2 in the rubyinstaller.exe. Still no luck. I believe it has to do with "glib2" whatever that is.

I am looking for advice on what to do next as I am sure I am missing something.

Thanks,
Edgar

(This is the regurgitation from my most recent attempt.)

```
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x64-mingw32]

C:\Users\Edgar>gem install squib
Fetching native-package-installer-1.0.9.gem
Fetching gio2-3.4.1.gem
Fetching highline-2.0.2.gem
Fetching gobject-introspection-3.4.1.gem
Fetching pkg-config-1.4.1.gem
Fetching cairo-1.16.5.gem
Fetching glib2-3.4.1.gem
Fetching classy_hash-0.2.1.gem
Fetching mercenary-0.3.6.gem
Fetching mini_portile2-2.4.0.gem
Fetching nokogiri-1.10.4-x64-mingw32.gem
Fetching cairo-gobject-3.4.1.gem
Fetching pango-3.4.1.gem
Fetching rubyzip-1.3.0.gem
Fetching roo-2.8.2.gem
Fetching gdk_pixbuf2-3.4.1.gem
Fetching rsvg2-3.4.1.gem
Fetching ruby-progressbar-1.10.1.gem
Fetching squib-0.15.3.gem
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config-0.29.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
Successfully installed pkg-config-1.4.1
Successfully installed native-package-installer-1.0.9
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-x86_64-cairo
warning: dependency cycle detected:
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-harfbuzz will be installed before its mingw-w64-x86_64-freetype dependency
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed cairo-1.16.5
Successfully installed classy_hash-0.2.1
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-x86_64-glib2
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-glib2-2.62.4-1 is up to date -- skipping
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing squib:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: D:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/glib2-3.4.1/ext/glib2
D:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I D:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200223-9340-259ydx.rb extconf.rb
checking for --enable-debug-build option... no
checking for -Wall option to compiler... yes
checking for -Waggregate-return option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wcast-align option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wextra option to compiler... no
checking for -Wformat=2 option to compiler... yes
checking for -Winit-self option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wlarger-than-65500 option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-declarations option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-format-attribute option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-include-dirs option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-noreturn option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-prototypes option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wnested-externs option to compiler... no
checking for -Wold-style-definition option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wpacked option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wpointer-arith option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wundef option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wout-of-line-declaration option to compiler... no
checking for -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wwrite-strings option to compiler... yes
checking for Homebrew... no
checking for gobject-2.0 version (>= 2.12.0)... yes
checking for gthread-2.0... yes
checking for unistd.h... no
checking for io.h... no
checking for g_spawn_close_pid() in glib.h... no
checking for g_thread_init() in glib.h... no
checking for g_main_depth() in glib.h... no
checking for g_listenv() in glib.h... no
checking for rb_check_array_type() in ruby.h... no
checking for rb_check_hash_type() in ruby.h... no
checking for rb_exec_recursive() in ruby.h... no
checking for rb_errinfo() in ruby.h... no
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby.h... no
checking for ruby_native_thread_p() in ruby.h... no
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl() in ruby.h... no
checking for rb_gc_register_mark_object() in ruby.h... no
checking for rb_exc_new_str() in ruby.h... no
checking for rb_enc_str_new_static() in ruby.h... no
checking for curr_thread in ruby.h,node.h... no
checking for rb_curr_thread in ruby.h,node.h... no
creating ruby-glib2.pc
creating glib-enum-types.c
creating glib-enum-types.h
creating Makefile

current directory: D:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/glib2-3.4.1/ext/glib2
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: D:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/glib2-3.4.1/ext/glib2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling glib-enum-types.c
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -I. -ID:/Ruby26-x64/include/ruby-2.6.0/x64-mingw32 -I/D/Ruby26-x64/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -I/D/Ruby26-x64/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I. -IC:/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12//INCLUDE  -I./.gem.20200223-9340-l8g9x  -I/D/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.6.0/x64-msvcrt  -ID:/Ruby26-x64/msys64/mingw64/include -ID:/Ruby26-x64/msys64/mingw64/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -ID:/Ruby26-x64/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0 -ID:/Ruby26-x64/msys64/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include -ID:/Ruby26-x64/msys64/mingw64/include -ID:/Ruby26-x64/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0 -ID:/Ruby26-x64/msys64/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include -DRUBY_GLIB2_COMPILATION -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-fast-math -Wall -Waggregate-return -Wcast-align -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wlarger-than-65500 -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wpointer-arith -Wundef -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wwrite-strings -mms-bitfields -pthread -mms-bitfields  -o glib-enum-types.o -c glib-enum-types.c'
make: *** [Makefile:244: glib-enum-types.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in D:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/glib2-3.4.1 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/glib2-3.4.1/gem_make.out

C:\Users\Edgar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like the version of glib2 that squib is calling for is not installing correctly on my Windows 10 system. After multiple attempts I discovered a work around that can get squib installed. It requires you to have a "subsystem for Linux" not as bad as it sounds, follow me:

**1.** Head to this [site](https://stackify.com/install-ruby-on-windows-everything-you-need-to-get-going/)

**2.** Scroll down to the "Using the Windows Subsystem for Linux" section.

**3.** Follow all instructions after "Using the Windows Subsystem for Linux" and before "Bonus points!".

**4.** Once ruby is installed. *Type the code below into your terminal:*

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

**5.** Once that is complete. *Type the code below into your terminal:*

```
sudo gem install squib
```

**6.** You will get through the majority of the installation and then you will get a "ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension." This is in reference to gdk_pixbuf2. *Type the code below into your terminal:*

```
sudo gem update rake
```

**7.** Finally, *type the code below into your terminal*:

```
sudo gem install squib
```

**8.** You are done and ready to use squib!

Having to update this rake file makes me think I should have updated the make file in my windows installation of ruby.